# Request to get the id from database is not working

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

Hi guys I am new in php I just started learning it I am making a simple e-commerce website using xampp local server I am facing this problem when i use get method for retrieving the specific id of a row:

```
  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
           $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id= '$id'" ;
                $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ('error');
              while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                  $discounted_price = $row['item_price'] - $row['item_discount'];

                  echo "
                       <div class='col-md-6'>
                       <h3 class='pp-title'>$row[item_title]</h3>
                       <img src='$row[item_image]' class='img-responsive' >
                       <div class='bottom'>

                       <div class='pull-right cutted-price text-muted'><del>$ $row[item_price]</del></div>
                       <div class='clearfix'></div>
                       <div class='pull-right disscounted-price'>$$discounted_price</div>
                       </div>
                       <h4 class='pp-dsc-title'>Description</h4>
                       <div class='pp-dsc-detail'>$row[item_description]</div>
                       </div> 

               ";
              }
           }else {
                echo "The request is not working";
            }
```

The URL I am trying to access this on is below:

```
http://localhost/ec/items.php?item_title%20=%20Beautiful-brown-Watch&id%20=%201
```

I am getting the else output "the request is not working" if i remove the if statement from above and simply write in the query id = '1' or '2' the data appear on web page but when i do for a specific id it doesn't work i use mysqli_real_escape_string for get rid of SQL injection if that is not proper way to get rid of SQL injection then guide me.

Comment: No `mysqli_real_escape` is not the way to avoid SQL injections. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/3072566) has all you need to know

Comment: Thanks I'll try this prepared statements

Comment: Your error message means that the parameter `id` is not present in `$_GET`. Are you calling your PHP page with something like `http://localhost/foo.php?id=X`? (where X is the id you want )

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: @ litelite this is my link http://localhost/ec/items.php?item_title%20=%20Beautiful-brown-Watch&item_id%20=%201

Comment: @johncasio please paste the exact URL you are trying to access in the question

Comment: @ Peter Featherstone this is the url http://localhost/ec/items.php?item_title%20=%20Beautiful-brown-Watch&id%20=%201

Comment: @johncasio don't post it in the comment. Instead edit your question to include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for the `$_GET` variable `id` yet you are passing in the parameter `item_id` according to your link.

In addition to this you also have extra spaces in your query string parameters which is causing the strange `%20` you are seeing in your URL, so please strip these out.

To get this working, you either need to change your URL to:

```
http://localhost/ec/items.php?item_title=Beautiful-brown-Watch&id=1
```

Or update your code to:

```
if(isset($_GET['item_id'])) {
   $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['item_id']);
```

You also need to check out parameterized queries as `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is not the way to keep yourself safe.

A great post on this can be found here [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Your code expect a parameter called `id` while you pass one called `item_id` change your URL to

http://localhost/ec/items.php?item_title=Beautiful-brown-Watch&id=1

And it should work.

Also note that when creating URL you should not include any space.